# How to create a dropzone in my div element?

Tags: dropzone.js

**Notes :** I tired all questions and answers  related this  topic.

I use `form` tag then work completely fine. See Code [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/mxxa0bk8/1/) .

I want to "place" a drop zone in my `div` tag, but somehow it doesn't work. See the code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/mxxa0bk8/2/).

**Snippet Example Below.**

```js
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
$("#mydropzone").dropzone({
    //url: "/file/post",
 addRemoveLinks: true,
 maxFilesize: 0.5,
 dictDefaultMessage: '<span class="text-center"><span class="font-lg visible-xs-block visible-sm-block visible-lg-block"><span class="font-lg"><i class="fa fa-caret-right text-danger"></i> Drop files <span class="font-xs">to upload</span></span><span>&nbsp&nbsp<h4 class="display-inline"> (Or Click)</h4></span>',
 dictResponseError: 'Error uploading file!'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.3.0/dropzone.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.3.0/dropzone.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.3.0/basic.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="clsbox-1" runat="server">
    <div class="dropzone clsbox" id="mydropzone">

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: did you ever check Developer console? It said, "Uncaught Error: No URL provided."

Comment: ya .. because i use `div` tag . i use `form` tag  then remove error . but i want to dropzone in div tag.

Comment: Why insist not using it on `<form>` tag?

Comment: my application requirement then i use div tag beacse i already use `form` tag in my form . then i use second time then not worked and error are occur.

Comment: i got my answer . very time consumer in research in Dropzone after then i got best Solution

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After a long research I have finally got the best solution.

---

### HTML

```html
<div class="clsbox-1" runat="server">
    <div class="dropzone clsbox" id="mydropzone"></div>
</div>
```

### JavaScript

```js
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    
// Dropzone class:
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#mydropzone", { url: "/file/post"});
    
// If you use jQuery, you can use the jQuery plugin Dropzone ships with:
$("div#myDrop").dropzone({ url: "/file/post" });
```

---

#### JSFiddle Demo [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/mxxa0bk8/3/)

Comment: I just can't get this to work with the latest version of dropzone =/. I don't understand why it is so difficult to just put it inside a div instead of a form =/